# Select on jsonb array on specific key/value

Tags: arrays, postgresql, jsonb

I have a jsonb field containing this data :

```
[{"FieldName":"wire1","Metadata":[{"Date":"2018-02-06T11:32:57.4022774+01:00","Source":"exampleSource"}]},
{"FieldName":"wire2","Metadata":[{"Date":"2018-02-06T11:32:57.4022774+01:00","Source":"exampleSource"}]},
{"FieldName":"wire3","Metadata":[{"Date":"2018-02-06T11:32:57.4022774+01:00","Source":"exampleSource"}]}]
```

What is the correct way to access the `FieldName = FieldValue` inside this array, as part of a select ? We tried `SELECT meta::json->0 FROM myTable` , and that returned null. (meta is the column's name containing the metaData)

What I hope to get is, in a select, to return all lines where FieldName = wire1, or where Source = exampleSource, or where both are true.

Comment: please elaborate - `FieldName = FieldValue`?.. I dontunderstand what you want to get

Comment: what's the expected exact result of your query?..

Comment: What I hope to get is, in a select, to return all lines where FieldName = wire1, or where Source = exampleSource, or where both are true.

Comment: again - all lines are not all rows - you mean all parent array elements?..

Answer (score 0):

what you need is **jsonb_array_elements**   function.

**->** returns an object

```
SELECT jsonb_array_elements(**columnName**)->'FieldName' FROM ....

returns FieldName object
```

**->>** returns text

```
SELECT jsonb_array_elements(**columnName**)->>'FieldName' FROM ....

returns "wire1" text
```